# Multiple scss Files Referencing One Main Style File

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm working on a React app and have three scss files, one being the main file that contains theme variable colors, while the other 2 are part of its' component folder.

Let's say I import main into the *contacForm* styles.css and apply the variable color. Things work as expected. BUT as soon as I import main into *keepInTouchForm* styles.scss, it removes the styling from *contactForm*

Question is why is this happening and what is the correct way to keep one main.scss file with all variables and reference across multiple scss files?

Here's my folder structure:

```
- components
-- contactForm
--- index.js
--- styles.scss

-- keepInTouchForm
--- index.js
--- styles.scss

- scss
-- main.scss
```

main.scss has the following code:

```
$theme-colors: (
  'primary': #00a677,
  'secondary': #dde1e7,
);
```

styles.scss inside contactForm folder code:

```
@import '../../scss/main.scss';

.form-control {
  border: 1px solid theme-color('secondary');
}
```

styles.scss inside keepInTouchForm folder code:

```
@import '../../scss/main.scss'; //breaks the above code
```

Comment: `theme-color('secondary');` does not work for me at all.

Answer (score 0):

`map-get` syntax seems to work well for me.

```
map-get($theme-colors, primary);
```